# Reduce code repetition in Groovy closures

Tags: groovy, closures, gradle, antbuilder

In a piece of Gradle build script, the amount of code i'm repeating is increasing. All tasks have a big part in common, except for a few lines:

```
task copyZipFile() {
    doLast {
        def remoteBuildProperties = getRemoteBuildProperties(project)
        ant {
            taskdef(name: 'ftp',
                    classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP',
                    classpath: configurations.ftpAntTask.asPath)

            ftp(server: remoteBuildProperties['host.name'],
                    userid: remoteBuildProperties['username'],
                    password: remoteBuildProperties['password'],
                    remotedir: 'some-folder', // This value differs from call to call
                    passive: 'true') {
                // The next two lines also are different per case, and might be less or more lines
                fileset(dir: rootProject.buildDir) { include(name: 'build.zip') }
                fileset(dir: rootProject.projectDir) { include(name: 'build.properties') }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like to repeat myself, so I'd like to reduce this code to a new helper method that does this trick, and a simple caller, something like:

```
task copyZipFile() {
    doLast {
        def remoteBuildProperties = getRemoteBuildProperties(project)
        upload(remoteBuildProperties, 'some-folder') {
            fileset(dir: rootProject.buildDir) { include(name: 'build.zip') }
            fileset(dir: rootProject.projectDir) { include(name: 'build.properties') }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the inner closure to your `upload` method as the final parameter.  Set the delegate to the original builder delegate so the inner closure calls get handled properly.  For example:

```
def upload(remoteBuildProperties, folder, body) {
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'ftp',
                classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP',
                classpath: configurations.ftpAntTask.asPath)

        ftp(server: remoteBuildProperties['host.name'],
                userid: remoteBuildProperties['username'],
                password: remoteBuildProperties['password'],
                remotedir: folder,
                passive: 'true') {
            body.delegate = delegate
            body()
        }
    }
}
```